# Issue with PDF rendering plugin

Tags: pdf, grails, grails-plugin

i'm working on a Grails application which needs to generate a PDF file. We are using Grails Rendering Plugin for that (https://gpc.github.io/rendering/guide/single.html).

It was working until now but we are facing an issue when generating the PDF :

```
ERROR:  'NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.'
10:52:53.752 [http-bio-8080-exec-76] ERROR StackTrace - Full Stack Trace:
org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:75) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$load.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:52) [XhtmlDocumentService.class:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166) [groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:40) [XhtmlDocumentService.class:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
```

...

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:755) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:359) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
        ... 203 common frames omitted
```

I don't understand the error as nothing has changed on the template file i use to generate the PDF. Also, everything is working fine on local deployment. It only fails when deployed on linux machines.

My guess is that something is wrong with the messages.properties file (which is used for the PDF). We tried to change encoding and line break but nothing seems to do the trick..

I have no idea about what i'm missing here.

Comment: Looks like you have issue with wrong version of xerces. Search PATH_TO_TOMCAT/webapps/YOUR_APP/WEB-INF/lib for xml-apis, xerces, xercesImpl and xmlParserAPIs. If you have 2 of them - exclude one in build.gradle

Comment: Thank you so much, effectively a new xercesImpl jar was the cause of the problem.